# Android listview items proprieties change when scrolling

Tags: android, listview

I'm building an app in which there is a listview (To-Do-List), This listview is being filled from SQLite DB. Here is the adapter :

```
public class ToDoListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener{

        private Context activity;
        List<String> content,status;
        private float x1,x2;
        static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 150;

        private LayoutInflater inflater=null;
        public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

        public ToDoListAdapter(Context a, List<String> n,List<String> fid) {
            activity = a;
            content=n;
            status=fid;


            inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.
                                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            // Create ImageLoader object to download and show image in list
            // Call ImageLoader constructor to initialize FileCache
            imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext(),"p");
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return content.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        /********* Create a holder Class to contain inflated xml file elements *********/
        class ViewHolder{

            public EditText text;

        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {

            if (getCount() != 0)
                return getCount();

            return 1;
        }

//      @Override
//      public int getViewTypeCount() {
    //
//       return getCount();
//      }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View vi=convertView;
            final ViewHolder holder;

            if(convertView==null){

                /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.todolistview_row, null);

                /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.text = (EditText) vi.findViewById(R.id.listcontent);



               /************  Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
                vi.setTag( holder );
            }
            else 
                holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();


            holder.text.setText(content.get(position));
            holder.text.setTypeface(todofont);
            holder.text.setSelection(holder.text.getText().length());
//          
//          
            final Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(vi.getContext().getAssets(),"fonts/MAXWELL REGULAR.ttf");
//          holder.text.setTypeface(font);


            if(status.get(position).equals("1"))
            {
                holder.text.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0b9a0a"));
                holder.text.setPaintFlags(holder.text.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            }
            if(status.get(position).equals("0"))
            {
                holder.text.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#fa2007"));
            }


            holder.text.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    showdialog(holder.text,"edittext","yes",position);


                //  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), Status.get(position),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    return false;
                }
            });


            holder.text.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //k=0;
                    if(keyCode == 66)
                    {

                        String task=holder.text.getText().toString().replace("\n","");

                        k++;
                        if(k>1)
                        {

                            content.set(position,  holder.text.getText().toString().replace("\n",""));
                            Status.add(position,"0");
                            //ids.add(position,ids.get(position));

                            //content.add(0,additem.getText().toString());
                            //Status.add(0,"0");
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//                          additem.setText("");
//                          additem.setVisibility(View.GONE);   

                            db.openDataBase();
                            db.update_table("todolist","Task", task,"_id",ids.get(position),"","");
                            db.close();


                            k=0;

                            hideSoftKeyboard();
                        }
                        else
                        {

                        }
                        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Enter Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Based on the status value returned from the database and added to the ArrayList **status**, the task is considered as **completed** or **pending**. if completed the edittext is colored green and **striked through**, if not the edittext is colored red.

The thing that's going wrong is that when scrolling the listview, all the edittexts are being **striked through**, any help please ?

Comment: what is `Status` (note the capital starting letter) and what is `Status.add(position,"0");` supposed to do?

Comment: status is an ArrayList filled with each task status using the SQLite database.

Status.add(position,"0"); is used when adding a new task

Comment: For me it seems like you rather try to update existing itme's state. Furthermore will this capitalized Status be some singleton or what. This is not the instance used in the adapter it seems to be

Comment: //Remove  View vi=convertView; `convertView=null;
           
            if(convertView==null){`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Thanks man it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rectify your `getView` section

At first Use this

```
//Remove View vi=convertView; 

   convertView=null; 
   if(convertView==null)
    {
    // Do your staff
    }
```

Comment: @MonzerYaghi Mine pleasure .Move ahead